# Drawing a circle using Core Graphics Context in iOS - Objective-C or Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cgcontext

I am drawing a circle in this way:

```
CGContextRef contextRef = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetLineWidth(contextRef, 2.0);
//CGContextSetRGBFillColor(contextRef, 0, 0, 1.0, 1.0);
//CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(contextRef, 0, 0, 1.0, 1.0);
 CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(contextRef, [color CGColor]);
CGRect circlePoint = (CGRectMake(coordsFinal.x, coordsFinal.y, 50.0, 50.0));

CGContextFillEllipseInRect(contextRef, circlePoint);
```

I wanted to know how can Make the inside of the circle empty so that I can see what there is behind it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You mean you only want the outline? Use `CGContextStrokeEllipseInRect` in that case.

```
CGContextRef contextRef = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetLineWidth(contextRef, 2.0);
CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(contextRef, [color CGColor]);
CGRect circlePoint = (CGRectMake(coordsFinal.x, coordsFinal.y, 50.0, 50.0));

CGContextStrokeEllipseInRect(contextRef, circlePoint);
```

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 3**

```swift
let currentContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
currentContext?.setLineWidth(2.0)
currentContext?.setFillColor(color.CGColor)
let circleRect = CGRect(x: coordsFinal.x, y: coordsFinal.y, width: 50.0, height: 50.0)

currentContext?.strokeEllipse(in: circleRect)
```